# To use return ticket of non-used forward ticket with AirBaltic?

Tags: air-travel, airbaltic

I cannot use the forward ticket, but I need the return ticket still.

Can you use the return ticket if you cannot use the forward ticket to the destination?

Comment: Generally, if you miss a flight, all subsequent flights on the ticket are canceled. You must notify the airline in advance and try to get the ticket changed. See e.g. *[Is it okay to board only the second flight of a return ticket?](/questions/18854)* and *[If I book a return journey with British Airways and miss the first flight, can I still use the return flight?](/questions/84939)* among others.

Comment: @choster Why should you notice the carrier that you cannot use the ticket? - - Assume you use only the forward ticket, but not the return.

Comment: If you want to use an outbound segment and skip all later segments, you are usually fine; many people do this deliberately as "hidden city ticketing." If you want to skip the outbound and use the return, however, you must notify the airline because otherwise, they will cancel the return. This is the case with most tickets on most airlines, anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 3):

From the airBaltic [General Conditions of Carriage](https://www.airbaltic.com/en/general-conditions-of-carriage):

> 5.4 SEQUENCE AND USE OF COUPONS CONTAINED IN THE TICKET
>
> 5.4.1    The Ticket You have purchased is valid only for the transportation as shown in the Ticket, from the point of departure via
>   any Agreed Stopping Places to the final destination. All of the
>   Ticket’s Coupons must be used in full and in the sequence specified in
>   the Ticket. If the Coupon sequence is not followed as specified in the
>   Ticket, the Ticket can be invalidated.
>
> 5.4.2    If the Coupon sequence as specified in the Ticket is not followed, or if other provisions regarding their use are not followed
>   (for example, if You do not show up for one of the flights indicated
>   in the Ticket), We or the Carrier operating the flight is entitled to
>   cancel any or all of the unused flights contained in your Ticket,
>   including Your return flight.
>
> 5.4.3    Should You wish to change any aspect of Your flights, and Your Ticket’s Tariff permits it, You must contact Us in advance. We
>   will calculate the charge for Your new flights and You will be given
>   the option of accepting Our offered changes and their conditions, or
>   maintaining the original Carriage as specified in the Ticket.

In other words, no. You must use the tickets in order, and failure to show up for your first flight can result in cancellation of the remaining flights on your itinerary. This is a standard practice of most airlines, though there are some exceptions (e.g. [easyJet](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/advice/Automatic-flight-cancellations/))

You would need to contact the airline to see what change fees apply to your particular ticket (or whether such changes are even allowed) and whether those fees are cheaper than buying a new one.

Comment: It would be nice to know what is the fee with AirBaltic.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 As airBaltic is a low-cost-carrier with lots of rules, it [depends on your ticket](https://www.airbaltic.com/en/change-flights) and whether you purchased the "possibility to change your flight" service. It can be anything from no changes allowed to free of charge, but they also say: "Route/destination changes are not permitted." It's worth talking to them, but they may well not permit such a change at all.

Comment: I did not pay for the possibility to make changes to the ticket.

Comment: You may very well need to cancel your ticket (getting a refund just for the taxes) and book a new one then. If you have travel insurance and your change of plans is due to a covered reason, you could make a claim. But you'll want to call the airline to see what they can do first.